# Flex Issue with crossdomain.xml and FileReference.upload

Tags: apache-flex

Greetings

I have a Flex application that does a variety of request to a web application located in a different domain. Thus I've made a custom crossdomain.xml to allow access from my Flex app. 
The content of this file is

```
> <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
> "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
> <cross-domain-policy>
>     <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
>     <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="*"/>
> </cross-domain-policy>
```

This crossdomain.xml is located in a subfolder in my webapp: http://host:port/services/crossdomain.xml
The services (some are http services others web services) are located all inside the services subfolder.

I'm loading the crossdomain.xml using Security.loadPolicyFile and everythings works fine. Until i tried to make a file upload using the FileReference Object. Even when my HTTP Form is located under the services subfolder and that I am correctly loading the crossdomain.xml file (I can do either http requests and web services requests ) everytime i try to do a file upload i get the infamous Security Sandbox Violation.

I am missing something? Is there any special instruction to allow file uploads? According to the Adobe documentation (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_10.html) everything is well configured. Any ideas?

Comment: What browser, OS and version of Flash Player are you using? There are known differences in behavior for FileReference based on the browser/OS. This could be another one of them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering

I'm using Flex sdk 3.2
SO: Mac OSX Leopard
Browser: Safari 3 and Firefox 3. Both with the Flash 10.0 r12 plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File upload in Flash Player uses the Socket API instead of the browser networking API.  So to do things this way you will need to have a [socket policy file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html).

An easier alternative is to do the upload via a RemoteObject.  To do this you will need to use the new FileReference APIs in Flash Player 10 so that you can read the bytes of the file client-side and then send them to the server inside a RemoteObject call.

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced the same issue with crossdomain.xml 404 not found.

We integrated flex with salesforce.com in our project and struck with crossdomain.xml error.

In login authentication, we used username and password for testing locally and in the fault we have given the server URL to connect to salesforce.com.

It was working fine in all browsers except chrome. Then made the changes first to check server URL and included the test username and password details in the fault function it worked fine with chrome as well. Not added any crossdomain.xml file to the root.

Might be with chrome browser initial test details was not overriden with the serverl URL on fault.